# Pass data between UitableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

My app is based on a tab bar controller, which contain three section, three `UITableViewController`.

I need to send a data from the first `UitableView` when a row is clicked  (`didselectedrowatindexpath`) to the second `UITableView`, but I really don't know how to do that, could you help me please.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using a `UITabBarController` if you want the selection of a cell to influence another table should you not be using a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with notifications by placing a postNotification call in the didselectedrowatindexpath method

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
```

and providinig observers in any of the other controllers that need to be aware of the change

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver selector:(SEL)notificationSelector name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
```

Check the [NSNotificationCenter class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: A better method would be to simply have a property in the second UITableViewController subclass that the first one sets in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: A consequence of that would be that the source of the information has to be aware of who/where all the consumers are and be prepared to notify them individually. It lacks scalability and makes the controllers dependent on each others' methods and properties rather than on the data.

Comment: Which is a terrible idea if the data changes.